# Adding html strings in Java properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to add Html string in properties file..??

Test.example=paragraph tag style='color:red;'  test paragraph tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them in below way:

```
Test.example=<p style='color: red;'>Content</p>
```